# Stop swiping-up control center on iOS from the web page

Tags: javascript, html, ios, mobile, web

On my mobile optimized web page I have some fixed element on the bottom which should be swiped up, but on iOS devices swiping up from the bottom causes opening control center.

Is there some hack or option to disable it from the web while person is on my page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am 99.999% sure the answer is **NO**. That would interfere with the standard user experience and iOS is not the kind of platform where that is supported.

Comment: @luk2302 you ruined all my plans! :) anyway thanks for answer